# Problemas de símbolos al exportar a excel con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy intentando exportar una tabla HTML a EXCEL a utilizando un método que encontré con Java Script, pero el problema es que no mantiene los caracteres especiales ni acentuaciones. Entiendo que es por la codificación de caracteres pero no consigo hacer que funcione.

```
function Exportar(){
  var tmpElemento = document.createElement('a');
  var data_type = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=ISO-8859-1';
  var tabla_div = document.getElementById('tblReporte');
  var tabla_html = tabla_div.outerHTML.replace(/ /g, '%20');
  tmpElemento.href = data_type + ', ' + tabla_html;
  tmpElemento.download = 'LISTADO.xls';
  tmpElemento.click();}
```

Comment: ¿Has probado a usar UTF-8 en el charset?

Comment: según el código que tengo, he probado ambos 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=ISO-8859-1'; y 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=UTF-8';

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He encontrado esta función que es similar y es al parecer más conocida, en ella ya esta solucionado el problema de charset. La variable 'uri' en esta función tiene el mismo objetivo que la variable 'data_type' en la función original, por lo que aquí se define tanto el tipo de archivo temporal que generamos, como así también la codificación. La diferencia entre ambas funciones es la manera de crear y descargar el archivo, ya que esta función define la variable de la misma manera, pero al momento de generar el archivo temporal, considera la información de codificación de caracteres entregada en la variable 'uri', lo que faltaba en la función presentada en el problema.

Agregar este tag en la pagina

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=UTF-8">
```

Reemplazar la función por lo siguiente

```
 function Exportar(){
        var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
        , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=UTF-8"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
        , base64 = function (s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
        , format = function (s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (m, p) { return c[p]; }) }

        var table = 'tblReporte';
        var name = 'nombre_hoja_calculo';

        if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
         var ctx = { worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML }
         window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
}
```

Comment: por favor especifica para que sirve la linea encodeURIComponent asi te ganaras tu puntuacion positiva ademas de venir en unos dias y marcar como cerrada tu pregunta

Comment: Una duda Bastian, ¿Cómo puedo cambiar el nombre del archivo ya que por default lo nombra "descarga.xls"?

Comment: Hola, revisa este enlace a ver si encuentras una respuesta https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283956/is-there-any-way-to-specify-a-suggested-filename-when-using-data-uri