# ¿Cómo exportar una tabla HTML a Excel con JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy intentando exportar una tabla de `html` con un método que encontré, pero al momento de abrirlo no hay ningún dato, desconozco las razones, pero por lo que he visto puede ser la compatibilidad con el navegador (uso Chrome), así qué, sí pudieran ayudarme se los agradezco, dejo el código del método que estoy intentando.

`JavaScript`

```
function exportarAExcel(){
        var downloadLink;
        var dataType = 'application/vnd.ms-excel';
        var tableSelect = document.getElementById("table");
        var tableHTML = tableSelect.outerHTML.replace(/ /g, '%20');

        // Specify file name
        filename = localStorage.getItem("filename") + ".xls";

        // Create download link element
        downloadLink = document.createElement("a");

        document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

        if(navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob){
            var blob = new Blob(['ufeff', tableHTML], {
                type: dataType
            });
            navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob( blob, filename);
        }else{
            // Create a link to the file
            downloadLink.href = 'data:' + dataType + ', ' + tableHTML;

            // Setting the file name
            downloadLink.download = filename;

            //triggering the function
            downloadLink.click();
        }
    }
```

`HTML`

```
<div class='d-flex justify-content-center' id="contentTable">
            <table class='table table-stripped' border=1 id="table">
                    <thead class= 'thead-dark'>

                    </thead>
                    <tbody>

                    </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

Cabe mencionar que la tabla la lleno con `JQuery` dependiendo de los filtros que se pongan, por lo tanto en el `html` está vacía

Comment: La pregunta no es clara. ¿A cuál formato de Excel te refieres? Podría ser .xls, .xlsx, enter otros específicos incluso podría ser CSV.

Comment: De acuerdo, con el metodo con el que intenté, lo exporta en un .xls

Comment: .xls es un formato obsoleto ¿En realidad quieres usar ese formato o es simplemente que agarraste lo primero que encontraste? Por cierto, msSaveOrOpenBlob no es un método estándar y está obsoleto (ref. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/msSaveOrOpenBlob)

Comment: Pues es el primero que encontré y lo intenté así, pero pues, sí hay un método mejor, me lo podrías compartir?

Comment: Edita tu pregunta para tener claro que es lo que estás buscando. Si fuera una pregunta de depuración de código falta detalles como la versión de jQuery que estás usando así como datos de entrada, el mensaje de error si es que ocurre uno y una descripción clara del resultado esperado. Ref. [ask]. Quizás valdría la pena que hicieras una pregunta sobre como usar las herramientas de desarrollador de Chrome para depurar el código como el que has incluido, incluso quizás una sobre cómo saber cuales son los formatos de Excel actuales.

Comment: De hecho estoy resaltando en la pregunta que estoy utilizando ese método que me encontré, y por el hecho de que dijeron en un comentario que agregara el html de la tabla fue que agregue una justificación por el hecho de que la tabla está vacía, asi qué, simplemente estoy diciendo que se me genera un problema al intentar ese metodo, no estoy pidiendo nada en especifico en cuanto formatos de excel, ni nada

Comment: Algunas preguntas relacionadas: [personalizar exportador de Excel](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/221305/65), [Tabla HTML a Excel (usando javascript)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/253677/65), [Problemas de símbolos al exportar a excel con JavaScript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/139873/65)